# Convert a Spark dataframe to a vector

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I want to predict the output class of a Spark `dataframe` using a *naive* classifier model. I use the structured streaming functionality of Spark 2.1.0.

When I try to do that:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="message", outputCol="logTokenize")
tokenizeData = tokenizer.transform(stream_df)

hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="logTokenize", outputCol="rawFeatures", numFeatures = 1000)
featurizedData = hashingTF.transform(tokenizeData)
stream_df = featurizedData.select("rawFeatures")

path = "/tmp/NaiveClassifier"
naive_classifier_model = NaiveBayesModel.load(spark.sparkContext, path)

predictions = naive_classifier_model.predict(stream_df)
```

I got the following error message:

> TypeError: Cannot convert type <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'> into Vector

`stream_df` is a Spark dataframe and I want to get a dataframe with `rawFeatures` and the predicted classes columns.

Answer (score 2):

Use *pyspark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler* to transform to a vector,

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['rawFeatures'], outputCol="features")
stream_df = vecAssembler.transform(featurizedData)
```

Also, you are using Tokenzier,Hasing TF transformers. So, I believe you can use an [ML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) pipeline to fit all the transfomers together.

It is just a suggestion. Have a look.

Comment: I tried that before, the problem I think is the Naive classifier object, when I try to call the `naive_classifier_model.fit(stream_df)` I got an error and I think I can't call the `predict` function with the output of the `VectorAssembler`. Yes, it's better to use a Pipeline but currently I do that to debug

Comment: you got the same error while tried with vectorassembler ?

Comment: I also am facing the same issue. Even after converting the dataframe column to vector and singling it out, I am still getting `Cannot convert type <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'> into Vector`. In my case I am using `Statistics.chiSqTest()` from `from pyspark.mllib.stat`

Answer (score 0):

Try using float:

```
path = "/tmp/NaiveClassifier"
naive_classifier_model = NaiveBayesModel.load(spark.sparkContext,path)

prediction= stream_df.rdd.map(lambda p:(float(naive_classifier_model.predict(p.rawFeatures))))
```

Comment: I got the following error message when I try that : `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'`, I use the structured streaming. In the programming guide it's marked that we can apply the `map` function of data frame

Comment: Whats the Spark version that you are using? try this- `prediction= stream_df.rdd.map(lambda p:(float(naive_classifier_model.predict(p.rawFeatures))))` Spark 2 has the direct map from dataframe removed